# Заменить фрагмент после переворота экрана

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть `LoadingFragment`, который отображается пока идет загрузка, по окончанию загрузки его заменяю на `ContentFragment`, если перевернуть экран во время загрузки, я ловлю  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`, при попытки заменить фрагмент. Как правильно реализовать такую задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно всё делать на одном фрагменте. Сделайте две `ViewGroup`: одна с `ProgressBar`, или что там у вас на этом `LoadingFragment`, другая с контентом, который на `ContentFragment`. При старте загрузки выставляете `setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE)` для `ProgressBar` и `setVisibility(Visibility.GONE)` для контента. По заверешнию загрузки инверитруете видимость. Вот и всё. По описанной вами ситуации, никакой второй фрагмент совершенно не нужен.